# What is the Big O of that pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis, pseudocode

```
x <--1
for i <--0 to n do
    k <-- i
   while k> 0 do
         x <-- x*2
         k <-- k-1
return x
```

Is it O (n)? Do while loop increase the complexity?

Comment: That\`s not O(n). The inner loop does increase the complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `i = 0`, inner loop runs `0` time
When `i = 1`, inner loop runs `1` time
When `i = 2`, inner loop runs `2` times
When `i = 3`, inner loop runs `3` times
...
When `i = n`, inner loop runs `n` times
Adding it all up: `0+1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2`
So the time complexity is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 0):

i agree with xashru above.  O(n^2)

Comment: please provide some more information about how you got to this conclusion.